# Parse dictionary behaviour strange

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, swift4, alamofire

Parse dictionary value if one `key` value is `null` and other is key not null.

Value from `source` the name key unable to parse if the value of `id` is `null`.  If the value of id not `null` then its returns the `name` value.

```
    {
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 70,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Bloombergquint.com"
            },
            "author": "Aman Kapadia, Forum Bhatt",
            "title": "Infibeam Auditors Raise Questions On Loans To Vendors - BloombergQuint",
            "description": "Auditors to Infibeam Avenues raise questions about loans to vendors.",
            "url": "https://www.bloombergquint.com/business/infibeam-auditors-raise-questions-on-loans-to-vendors",
            "urlToImage": "https://images.assettype.com/bloombergquint%2F2018-02%2F11136839-3c0c-4356-b4d3-c918f4d417ad%2F323233043_1-9%20(1).jpg?rect=0%2C204%2C4000%2C2100&w=1200&auto=format%2Ccompress",
            "publishedAt": "2019-02-15T14:58:37Z",
            "content": "Auditors to Infibeam Avenues Ltd. raised questions about loans to vendors and how it recognises revenue in a fresh concern for the online retailer. SRBC &amp; Co. LLP, the audit arm of EY, and Shah &amp; Taparia sought more information to justify the rational… [+1985 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Moneycontrol.com"
            },
            "author": null,
            "title": "RBI lifts cap on FPI investments in corporate bonds - Moneycontrol.com",
            "description": "While the provision was aimed at incentivising FPIs to maintain a portfolio of assets, market feedback indicates that foreign portfolio investors (FPIs) have been constrained by this stipulation, the RBI said.",
            "url": "https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/rbi-lifts-cap-on-fpi-investments-in-corporate-bonds-3545571.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://static-news.moneycontrol.com/static-mcnews/2017/03/RBI-770x433.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2019-02-15T13:26:00Z",
            "content": "The Reserve Bank of India (RBI) Friday withdrew the 20 per cent limit on investments by FPIs in corporate bonds of an entity with a view to encourage more foreign investments. As part of the review of the FPI investment in corporate debt undertaken in April 2… [+696 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Rushlane.com"
            },
            "author": "Rishabh Jain",
            "title": "2019 Honda Civic Review test drive - Still got the charm? - RushLane",
            "description": "Honda is back with the Civic in India. But does it have enough to attract those who love driving?",
            "url": "https://www.rushlane.com/2019-honda-civic-review-test-drive-12297473.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.rushlane.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/2019-honda-civic-review-test-drive-photos-specs-launch-price-14.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2019-02-15T12:59:00Z",
            "content": "The Civic happens to be one of most loved brands from Honda in India. Globally too, it is one of those rare brands which have seen 10 proper generation changes. It is sold in multiple body types like Sedan, Coupe and Hatchback, however the Indian market only … [+8342 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Team-bhp.com"
            },
            "author": "Aditya Nadkarni",
            "title": "Maruti Swift, Dzire, Ertiga could get CNG variants - Team-BHP",
            "description": "According to a media report, Maruti Suzuki might introduce CNG variants of its cars in the years to come. The move could be taken in response to comply with the BS-VI emission norms, which are scheduled ...",
            "url": "https://www.team-bhp.com/news/maruti-swift-dzire-ertiga-could-get-cng-variants",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.team-bhp.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/1_639.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2019-02-15T12:43:30Z",
            "content": "According to a media report, Maruti Suzuki might introduce CNG variants of its cars in the years to come. The move could be taken in response to comply with the BS-VI emission norms, which are scheduled to be implemented in 2020 and tighter fuel efficiency no… [+1119 chars]"
        }
   ]
}
```

ModelClass

```
private struct Headline: Decodable {
    let author: String
    let title: String
    let source: Source

    struct Source: Codable {
        var id : String
        var name : String
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case author
        case title
        case source
    }
}
```

Inside ViewController

```
let url = ""
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
    // It is necessary for correct decoding. Timestamp -> Date.

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
//                    ??? how to assing here! access the value global????
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Inside cellForRowAt

```
cell.lbl_NewsTitle?.text = headlines[indexPath.row].title
cell.lbl_NewsSource?.text = headlines[indexPath.row].source["name"]
```

Its print only when id hold some String value else source.name return nil

Can any one advice why its like this?
I am first time using swift language. :(

Comment: Where's your parsing code? You simply show a JSON, but no code along with it...

Comment: Looks like you are not creating the source object if the id is null.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Let me edit my question so its will have enough source code for understanding what I have done.

Comment: Can any one let me know how to extract response data to bring out values of name from source dictionary?

Comment: Consider to drop `ObjectMapper` in favor of the `Codable` protocol. It's built-in, more efficient and an `NSObject` subclass is not needed.

Comment: @vadian. I drop ObjectMapper and swift codable !  I updated my question. too please let me know is correct way to do?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Decodable` you have to add the umbrella struct and you have to declare `author` in `Headline` and `id` in `Source` as optional because they can be `null`. All CodingKeys are synthesized.

```
struct Response : Decodable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Headline]
}

struct Headline: Decodable {
    let author: String?
    let title: String
    let source: Source
    let publishedAt : Date

    struct Source: Decodable {
        let id: String?
        let name: String
    }
}
```

Rather than `.secondsSince1970` the date decoding strategy must be `.iso8601`.

This code assignes the `articles` array to the data source and reloads the table view on the main thread

```
let url = ""

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
            do {
               let result = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: response.data!)
               self.headlines = result.articles
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
               }
            } catch { print("Decoding error:", error) }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

The data source array must be declared as

```
var headlines = [Headline]()
```

In `cellForRowAt` write

```
let headline = headlines[indexPath.row]
cell.lbl_NewsTitle?.text = headline.title
cell.lbl_NewsSource?.text = headline.source.name
```